# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select:[id*="devices_0_command"]

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I recently upgraded some code from jquery 1.4 to 1.9 and now I am getting the following error when trying to find a particular element on my page, a select box. I'm changing its color to confirm I've matched the correct element..but now I'm getting a syntax error as per below;

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select:[id*="devices_0_command"]
```

My syntax is as below;

```
$('select:[id*="devices_0_command"]').css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
```

Thank you.

Comment: remove `:` from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ':' from the selection:

```
$('select[id*="devices_0_command"]')
```